# CSS: how to select an element that has ALL 4 classes in any order

Tags: css, class

I have the need of select an element that has ALL classes I specify in any order.

Example:

I have to apply a style to these:

```
<tr class="class1 class2 class3 class4">
<tr class="class3 class2 class4 class1">
<tr class="class4 class3 class1 class2">
```

But not to these:

```
<tr class="class1">
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">
<tr class="class3 class1">
```

I need something like this:

```
.class4 AND .class2 AND .class1 AND .class3{color: #ff0000;}
```

Any chance to do this with?

Answer (score 4):

Your selector should go like this `.class1.class2.class3.class4` and this will select all elements that have all 4 classes and the order doesn't matter.

```css
.class1.class2.class3.class4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4">lorem</div>
<div class="class3 class2 class4 class1">lorem</div>
<div class="class4 class3 class1 class2">lorem</div>

<div class="class1">lorem</div>
<div class="class1 class2 class3">lorem</div>
<div class="class3 class1">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

.class1.class2.class3.class4 
{color: #ff0000;

}